# Ansible serialize roles

Tags: ansible

I have some tasks which needs to be executed one server at time. I have separated them in a separate role. My question is if it's possible somehow to tell a role to run one on one server at time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs the playbook to be split in different playbooks, then include the first playbook on the second one which can be set serial. Therefore all the roles on the first playbook will be run in paralells while the rest of the roles from the second playbook will be run in serial. Also if any facts needs to be carried over from the first playbook to the second one fact caching needs to be enabled.